# Calculate distance in openstreetmap with josm?

Tags: java, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm new to openstreetmap. I want to use openstreetmap in a java application to get distance between two points. And also to find more information about a particular road, etc. 
I discovered [JOSM](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/), but all I need is to calculate distance between two points in a road, also get some more information about that road, when necessary. Anybody knows which class/methods in JSOM will help me do that? Or is there any other simpler method/api to do that with OpenStreetMap?

Comment: Are you looking for a [routing](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing) API?

Comment: Somewhat Yes, I guess... I too stumbled upon it... But I'd still be grateful if somebody who's experience in doing that in java/python show that with some example...

Comment: Creating requests to GraphHopper or OSRM is not very difficult. This involves usually sending a HTTP request and parsing the response, which is often JSON.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I'll try!

Comment: Found couple of interesting links - https://github.com/ustroetz/python-osrm and another one - http://sensitivecities.com/bikeshare.html#.Vqhi9asVveQ Will try out..